# What is the best practise to overwrite css from theme in drupal?

Tags: drupal-8

I'm using drupal 8 and I have to customize already existing theme (downloaded from drupal site).

Should I just make changes in specific files in docroot/themes/theme_name or do I have to create subdirectory somewhere in docroot/sites and there put the files that I wanted to change? I mean make there files with css styling that I want to change.

Comment: I guess here is the answer: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/creating-a-sub-theme and here: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/folder-structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

[drupal.org/theme-guide/8/creating-a-sub-theme](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/8/creating-a-sub-theme)

and here: [drupal.org/theme-guide/8/folder-structure](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/8/folder-structure)